# wxPython DataViewCtrl Child Text Item Editor Appears Incorrectly

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been attempting to use wxPython to create a program which requires a tree/list editor. However, I quickly ran into a problem of the text edit box for children items appearing at the bottom of the list, rather than in place. In the simplified example shown below, I double clicked to edit the cell next to AA, however the edit box appeared in the last row.

[image]

When I edit a parent cell, however, there is no issue and it appears correctly.
[image]

I have attached the code below. I would appreciate any suggestions for resolving this issue. Thanks!

```
import wx
import wx.dataview as dv

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.value = ''

class DVC_Model(dv.PyDataViewModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data

        self.UseWeakRefs(True)


    def GetColumnCount(self):
        return 2

    def GetColumnType(self, col):
        return 'string'

    def GetChildren(self, item, children):
        if not item:
            for child in self.data.children:
                children.append(self.ObjectToItem(child))
            return len(self.data.children)

        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

        for child in obj.children:
            children.append(self.ObjectToItem(child))
        return len(obj.children)

    def GetParent(self, item):
        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

        if obj.parent is None:
            return dv.NullDataViewItem

        return self.ObjectToItem(obj.parent)

    def IsContainer(self, item):
        if not item:
            return True

        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

        return len(obj.children) > 0

    def HasContainerColumns(self, item):
        return True

    def GetValue(self, item, col):
        if not item:
            return [root.name, root.value][col]

        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

        return [obj.name, obj.value][col]

    def SetValue(self, variant, item, col):
        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)
        if col == 1:
            obj.value = variant

        return True

    def GetAttr(self, item, col, attr):
        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

        if len(obj.children) > 0:
            attr.SetColour('blue')
            attr.SetBold(True)
            return True

        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()

    window = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Test title", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
    window.SetFocus()

    dvc = dv.DataViewCtrl(window, style=wx.BORDER_THEME | dv.DV_ROW_LINES | dv.DV_VERT_RULES | dv.DV_MULTIPLE)

    root = Node('root', None)

    A = Node('A', root)
    AA = Node('AA', A)
    AB = Node('AB', A)
    A.children = [AA, AB]

    B = Node('B', root)
    BA = Node('BA', B)
    BB = Node('BB', B)
    B.children = [BA, BB]

    root.children = [A, B]

    model = DVC_Model(root)
    dvc.AssociateModel(model)

    dvc.AppendTextColumn('Name', 0)
    dvc.AppendTextColumn('Value', 1, mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)


    window.Show(True)

    app.MainLoop()
```

Update: I tested the program on Linux and get a segmentation fault. The wxPython demo programs work fine. Maybe that can help identify the issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the error on Linux, I began doing further testing and realized that I was returning the root node as a parent in `GetParent()` for nodes A and B. However, this node should be invisible to wxPython and I needed to be returning `wx.NullDataViewItem` instead. The solution I found was to either modify `GetParent()` or instantiate the objects without a parent as follows:

```
def GetParent(self, item):
    obj = self.ItemToObject(item)

    if obj.parent is None or obj.parent == self.data:  # if the parent is the invisible root node, return null
        return dv.NullDataViewItem

    return self.ObjectToItem(obj.parent)
```

```
root = Node('root', None)

A = Node('A', None)  # root changed to None
AA = Node('AA', A)
AB = Node('AB', A)
A.children = [AA, AB]

B = Node('B', None)  # root changed to None
BA = Node('BA', B)
BB = Node('BB', B)
B.children = [BA, BB]

root.children = [A, B]
```